# Behaviour of scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [confusion in scanf() with & operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440406/confusion-in-scanf-with-operator)

Why we need a & in scanf for inputting integer and why not for characters.
Do the & in scanf refers to merory location while getting input.

Eg:-

```
main()
{
int a;
char c;

scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%c"c);
}
```

Comment: we need & with chars but we don't need for strings (char[] or char*)

Comment: The second call to `scanf()` should be `scanf("%c", c)`.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each conversion specifier, `scanf()` expects the corresponding argument to be a pointer to the proper type: `%d` expects an argument of type `int *`, `%f` expects an argument of type `double *`, `%c` and `%s` both expect an argument of type `char *`, etc.

The difference between `%c` and `%s` is that the former tells `scanf()` to read a *single* character and store it in the location specified by the corresponding argument, while the latter tells `scanf()` to read multiple characters until it sees a 0-valued character and store all those characters in the buffer starting at the location specified by the argument.

You need to use the `&` operator on your arguments if they are not already of pointer type.  For example:

```
int x;
int *px = some_valid_memory_location_such_as_&x;
char c;
char *pc = some_valid_memory_location_such_as_&c;
...
scanf("%d", &x); // x is not a pointer type, so we must use the & operator
scanf("%d", px); // px is a pointer type, so we don't need the & operator
scanf("%c", &c); // etc.
scanf("%c", pc); // etc.
```

Where things get confusing is reading *strings* of characters (using the `%s` conversion specifier):

```
char buf[SIZE];
scanf("%s", buf);    // expression 'buf' *implicitly* converted to pointer type
```

Why don't we need the `&` operator in this case?  It has to do with how C treats array expressions.  When the compiler sees an expression of array type (such as `buf` in the `scanf()` call), it will implicitly convert the expression from type `N-element array of T` to `pointer to T`, and set its value to the address of the first element in the array.  This value is not an lvalue -- it cannot be assigned to (so you can't write something like `buf = foo`).  The only exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of either the `sizeof` or `&` operators, or if the array expression is a string literal being used to initialize another array:

```
char *p = "This is a test";  // string literal implicitly converted to char *,
                             // string *address* written to p
char a[] = "This is a test"; // string literal not implicitly converted,
                             // string *contents* copied to a
```

In short, the expression `buf` is *implicitly* converted from type `char [SIZE]` to `char *`, so we don't need to use the `&` operator, and in fact the type of the expression `&buf` would be `pointer to SIZE-element array of char`, or `(*)[SIZE]`, which is not what `scanf()` expects for the `%s` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 6):

The ampersand symbol is required in both cases. scanf requires pointers (you were probably thinking of char* or char[] - they are pointers themselves).

Answer (score 2):

Scanf reads input to a memory *address*.  `a` is the value held by a.  `&a` is the location of `a` in memory.

In your code above, the `c` should be `&c`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `scanf()` needs pointers, and `&a` is the pointer to an integer.

In your example, you need a comma and an ampersand in front of the `c`.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    char c;
    char s[21];

    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%c", &c);   // Fixed!
    scanf("%20s", s);
    printf("a = %d, c = %c, s = <<%s>>\n", a, c, s);

}
```

If you were reading a string, you would pass the string - a pointer to char - to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide **scanf** with pointer, that's why you have **&** in **scanf("%d",&a)**;
. **scanf("%c"c)**; will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong. If you have a

```
char c;
```

then you need to add an `&` to the name when calling `scanf`:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

*However*, if your variable is already a pointer, for example because it is a `char[]` (which is a fancy syntax for pointers), you have to omit the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of the ampersand (&) as "address of". So you'd read `&a` as "address of a".

Also, I tried compiling this but it warned me on gcc:

```
Warning: format "%c" expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'
```

Which is true, since a char is basically an int.