# Why is address operator not needed in scanf?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

Why is address operator not needed for stud->names.firstName?
But address operator is required in &stud->studentid ?

```
struct student {
    struct
    {
        char lastName[10];
        char firstName[10];
    } names;
    int studentid; 
};


int main()
{  
    struct student record;
    GetStudentName(&record);
    return 0;
}

void GetStudentName(struct student *stud)
{
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", stud->names.firstName); //address operator not needed
    printf("Enter student id: ");
    scanf("%d", &stud->studentid);  //address operator needed
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does scanf() need & operator in some cases, and not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440406/why-does-scanf-need-operator-in-some-cases-and-not-others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only not needed, it would be incorrect. Because arrays<sup>1</sup> are automatically converted to pointers.

The following

```
scanf("%s", stud->names.firstName);
```

is equivalent to

```
scanf("%s", &stud->names.firstName[0]);
```

so using the address of operator here is redundant because both expressions are equivalent.

Using it like you do for the `"%d"` format specifier
(**THIS IS WRONG**)

```
scanf("%s", &stud->names.firstName);
```

would be wrong and actually undefined behavior would occur.

**NOTE**: Always verify the value returned from `scanf()`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Also known as the *array name*</sub>

Comment: Why would it be wrong to take the address? Since `firstName` is an array, I would expect it to work. It wouldn't work if `firstName` were a pointer, though.

Comment: @RolandIllig It is equivalent to taking the address of a pointer. The important difference is that pointer arithmetics will be different.