# Golang array input not working as expected

Tags: go

I have a written a simple piece of code to read array in golang

```
func main(){
  var n int
  fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
  var arr [200] int

  for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("\nEnter %d:", i)
    fmt.Scanf("%d", arr[i])
  }

}
```

It is generating below output:

```
go run array_input.go 
5

Enter 0:1

Enter 1:
Enter 2:2

Enter 3:
Enter 4:4
```

Here when I enter value for array location 0, it automatically jumps to array location 2 without taking any value for array location 1. I am not able to understand why it is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add '&' before arr[i]

```
func main(){
  var n int
  fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
  var arr [200] int

  for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("\nEnter %d:", i)
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &arr[i])
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.But why we need to add & before array element as it represent poisition of memory only.

Comment: '&' operator was used in the function to store the user inputted value in the address of arr
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3440480/8284461